# Laravel : "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" while pass variable into closure

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder, laravel-7

I get an error like this
[ErrorException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGACP.png)

This my link index

```
<td><a href="{{route('detail_face_to_face', $tm->id)}}">{{$cmface}}</a></td>
```

This my Routes

```
Route::get('/detail_face_to_face/{id}', 'FaceToFaceController@detail')->name('detail_face_to_face');
```

This my Controller

```
public function detail($id)
    {
        $xclass = DB::table('face_to_face')->select('Class')->where('id', $id)->first();
        $tface = DB::table('tbclass')
            ->select('tbclass.F_Name','tbclass.Class')
            ->where('tbclass.Class', $xclass)
            ->whereNotExists(function ($query) use ($id) {
                $query->select('id_user')
                      ->from('absent')
                      ->where([['absent.id_face_to_face', $id],['absent.type_face_to_face', '1'],])
                      ->whereRaw('absent.id_user = tbclass.ID_No');
            })
            ->orderBy('tbclass.F_Name', 'ASC')
            ->paginate(10);
        return view('face_to_face.detail',['tface' => $tface]);
    }
```

This my face_to_face.detail page

```
<table class="table">
   <thead style="white-space:nowrap;">
       <tr>
           <th>No</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Class</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody style="white-space:nowrap;">
       @if($tface->count()===0)
       <tr>
           <td class="table-success text-center" colspan="10"><< Data is Empty >></td>
       </tr>
       @else
       @foreach($tface as $no => $tm)
       <tr>
           <td>{{ ++$no + ($tface->currentPage()-1) * $tface->perPage() }}</td>
           <td>{{$tm->F_Name}}</td>
           <td>{{$tm->Class}}</td>
       </tr>
       @endforeach
       @endif
   </tbody>
</table>
{{ $tface->links() }}
```

if I click the link on the index page, i get that error

Can anyone help ???

Comment: what this `$cmface` variable contains? is it string or object?

Comment: What is `$tm`? What is `$cmface`? Please post the full view code.

Comment: on which kine you get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you dd($xclass)?

Error is in, ->where('tbclass.Class', $xclass). You probably do ->where('tbclass.Class', $xclass->Class)

Regard